# Is there anything that we can only achieve with SASS not with css?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

We can use sass variables to store some styles and we can nest via sass. Yes they are good
but we can achieve those by ordinary css3? We can use classes and CSS selectors instead of nesting.
Is there anything in sass that we can only achieve via sass like that?
I'm eager to see the advantages thank you.

Comment: mixins, operators, import, modularity there are lot of features

Comment: My two cents sass is just css with more features... it can all be converted to normal css.
It is just alot easier to work with sass due to etc variables

Comment: "For" loops is one of things you can't do with native CSS, others like variables and mixins are already available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mixins, loops, operators, import, modularity there are lot of features in sass which make it powerful.

There are pitfalls too, overnesting rules and inheritance. If not written properly then 10kb code will easily double to 20.

Comment: If not written properly then 10 kb code will easily double to 20.This is noted,Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anything in sass that we can only achieve via sass?

Since SASS compiles into CSS, by definition, there is nothing that can be achieved only via SASS.

SASS is merely a heavy layer of syntactic sugar on top of CSS.